# Using Twisted with Kivy on a Windows Machine

Tags: python, kivy, twisted

I am attempting to get the example for using [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) with [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) on Windows 7 using Python 3.6 and the latest releases of Twisted and Kivy. Following the example located on the Kivy website entitled [Integrating with Other Frameworks](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/other-frameworks.html).

Using the code provided on the Kivy Website verbatim, the following error appears.

```
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\support.py", line 172, in install_twisted_reactor
 "_threadselect interface of twisted is not available on Python 3."
NotImplementedError: _threadselect interface of twisted is not available on Python 3.
```

Is there a workaround or way to edit Twisted to work with Python 3 until it is ported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twisted's "_threadedselect" has been ported to Python 3 and [Kivy has been updated](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/commit/c629168ec3f35a6700cbb40e8bfae06b05783897) to reflect this.  However, Kivy has not been released since this change was made.  You could try urging the Kivy project to release a version including this fix.

Or perhaps you could take the `kivy.support` module from master@HEAD and use it instead.